# C# - Get version of referenced DLL that app was built against (NOT what it references at run time)

Tags: c#, .net, dll, build, reference

I have an application that references a DLL that is from a separate VS solution. The application is of course built against a specific version of that DLL. At run time however it is possible that a different (higher or lower) version of the DLL is present. I want the app to be able to display to the user that it is expecting version X of the reference DLL to be present.

How do I retrieve (at run time) the version of the referenced DLL that the app was built against?

Note that solutions such as the following give the version of the referenced DLL that is present at run time, **which is not what I want**:

typeof(MyCompany.MyLibrary.SomeType).Assembly.GetName().Version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got interested by this and verified serveral methods. In code below, main assembly references DummyDll.dll, and it was built against version 1.0.0.2 of this dll, but really version 1.0.0.3 is loaded. Then I try mono.Cecil, Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies() and the same but for reflection-only loaded assembly:

```
internal class Program {
    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        new Class1().Test(); // otherwise DummyDll will not be referenced.
        var asm = Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
        foreach (var reference in asm.MainModule.AssemblyReferences) {
            if (reference.FullName.Contains("DummyDll"))
                Console.WriteLine(reference.FullName);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(Class1).Assembly.FullName);
        Console.WriteLine();
        foreach (var referenced in Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies()) {
            if (referenced.FullName.Contains("DummyDll"))
            Console.WriteLine(referenced.FullName);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        var asm2 = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().FullName);            
        foreach (var referenced in asm2.GetReferencedAssemblies()) {
            if (referenced.FullName.Contains("DummyDll"))
                Console.WriteLine(referenced.FullName);
        }            
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Here is the results:

DummyDll, Version=1.0.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

DummyDll, Version=1.0.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

DummyDll, Version=1.0.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

DummyDll, Version=1.0.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

Results show that *all* three methods produce same result and that is result which you need. Only way which shows real version of loaded assembly is typeof(Class1).Assembly. So easiest way to get what you want is to use Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies().

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies().

Answer (score 2):

You could store the information about the referenced dlls's in the app.config. But be careful, this information can be changed from any user who has access to the app.config. If i find some thing else, i will report it to you.

Is [Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/System.Reflection.Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies(v=VS.110).aspx) working in your case?

Comment: Now I look at Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies() it does produce the right version. I marked Evk's answer as accepted because it had more detail although you did suggest this idea before him ... sorry!

Answer (score 0):

.NET assemblies contain alot of info, including assemblies they were built against.

To look at the data:
Download `CFF Explorer`, drag a .net assembly in it, and expand:
`.NET Directory --> MetaData Streams --> #~ --> Tables --> AssemblyRef`

There is the data you are looking for :)

Now to obtain this information automatically, you could dive into the format of how all this info is stored (it's very interesting, altho it might be a bit too much), or you could use `Mono.cecil`, a library which is built to analyze .NET modules.

If you want an example, look at [`ILSpy`](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy), a .net disassembler.

Also, read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata_(CLI)

*edit: if the solution from `BendEg` works for you, that is far simpler than any of what i described :)*